# Netbeans - Subversion and Mercurial in one project

Tags: svn, mercurial, netbeans

i have php project which is versioned under svn. Now i started to do local versioning throught hg. The subversion, for collaboration with team, remains. After restart netbeans working with the project as with only Mercurial versioned.

**Is there way to use both? Or is it possible to tell NB to use just one of them?**

- Ubuntu - 9.10
- NB 6.8
- SVN - 1.6.5
- Mercurial -  1.3.1

Comment: I've temporaly solve this by move the .hg folder somwhere else, and when i want to use hg i make a symbolic link. I hope it's not a final solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you stick with hg and try hgsubversion:

http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion

Or why do you need both?

Comment: It was becouse we used svn and i wanted to use mercurial for my local versioning( svn does not have local repository ). From the four things i still use just ubuntu :) but thank you for your response

Comment: you can create local repo with svn too